# Keep the first instance of a string across columns in R

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this:

```
step1  |  step2  |  step3  |  step4
A          A         B         C
A          A         NA        NA
```

What I would like to achieve is this

```
step1  |  step2  |  step3  |  step4
A     |     B    |     C    |     NA
A     |    NA     |    NA     |    NA
```

I tried first transposing and then running this

```
table4 <- table3[match(unique(table3[,1]), table3[,1]), ]
```

but this cut off the table to the quantity of unique strings matched.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to loop through the rows, `replace` the `duplicated` elements to `NA`, then `order` by the missing values, transpose the output and assign it to the original data

```
table3[] <- t(apply(table3, 1, function(x) {
         x1 <- replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)
         x1[order(is.na(x1))]}))
table3
#  step1 step2 step3 step4
#1     A     B     C  <NA>
#2     A  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

#### data

```
table3 <- structure(list(step1 = c("A", "A"), step2 = c("A", "A"), 
    step3 = c("B", NA), step4 = c("C", NA)), .Names = c("step1", 
  "step2", "step3", "step4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked very nicely. I appreciate your help.